# PHPMailer Error: Called Mail() without being connected

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

i am trying to send a mail using PHPMailer, It works on my localhost but when i use it on byethost.com, a free hosting website, it says "PHPMailer Error: The following From address failed: vinceagno@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected"

I've tried changing the FROM address but still same result.

here are my codes.

```
<?php
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'; // "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" didn't worked
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
// or try these settings (worked on XAMPP and WAMP):
// $mail->Port = 587;
// $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';


$mail->Username = "XXXXXXXX@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "XXXXXXXX";

$mail->IsHTML(true); // if you are going to send HTML formatted emails
$mail->SingleTo = true; // if you want to send a same email to multiple users. multiple emails will be sent one-by-one.

$mail->From = "vinceagno@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Hotdog";

$mail->addAddress("vince_agno@live.com","User 1");


$mail->Subject = "Testing PHPMailer with localhost";
$mail->Body = "Hi,<br /><br />This system is working perfectly.";

if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Message was not sent <br />PHPMailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
else
    echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try and set Host to smtp.gmail.com

Comment: It could simply be that the server provider is blocking the Port. Probebly to prevent (free) users from using their server as a spam server ;)

Comment: when i change it to smtp.gmail.com i get an authorization error @coeaken

Comment: First up, you're using an old version of PHPMailer - update it. Don't use ssl/465 for gmail; use tls/587. Take a look at the [gmail example code](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) provided with PHPMailer. You don't need to call `singleTo` if you're only adding one address anyway.